# How to configure absolute imports in CRA created app via jsconfig?

Tags: visual-studio-code, create-react-app

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I did it just like in the official guide, but vscode gives me an error, that dotenv types file hadn't found (moreover, it gives me this error 3 times in a row). I looked for the answer in net, but didn't find a man with the same problem, most of them is trying to setup more difficult configs. How can I make it works?